# Input form & horizontal list are mysteriously misaligned in Chrome

Tags: css, list, firefox, input

I'm working on a small business website. Nearly finished except for this one last (infuriating) styling issue:

I can't get the email signup form and social media links in the header to line up. There is a margin difference of 1px in height between browsers.

The Signup is a form and the Social media links are part of a ul list. When I add margin to either element, Chrome and IE misalign. When I subtract the 1px, Firefox misaligns.

The site is built on Wordpress with a theme that I've heavily modified.

Here is the site: http://twistbikes.com ... You can see the offending articles in the top right hand corner.

Here's a screenshot: http://twistbikes.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/widget-area.jpg

Any clues much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give `margin:0` and `padding:0` to both the textbox and button elements.

Mention in the below block of code:

```
input, select, textarea {
     /* other properties */
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mr_Green. With this addition and some extra fiddling with widths, it appears to have worked. Much appreciated.